# I cant get the value of what I input from cell b2

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google script range doesn't work properly from mobile I can't get the value of what I input from cell b2 and the value of a10 is always "Range".

```
function myfunction(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WfEJyQweOklYFfQbQKxXsDZy2pCElEwBq_DlhxfS9SM/edit?format=drivesdk").getActiveSheet();
    var name = ss.getRange('b2').setValue();
    var name2 = ss.getRange('a10').setValue(name);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure to write code inside a code block, so that it is easier for us to read and understand.

Comment: To get Value, use getValue(). To set, use set

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You need to use `getValue()` to get the value from cell B2, not `setValue()`.*

#### Code Fix:

You need to change:

```js
var name = ss.getRange('b2').setValue();
```

to:

```js
var name = ss.getRange('b2').getValue();
```

#### Referneces:

- [Class Range - Method `getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [Class Range - Method `setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)